# SQL - narrowing terms by a differencing method

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

I have a SQL database I am trying to access from, what I require is the average for all terms given a difference between the max and min of each entry being above a certain threshold.

So, for interests sake say we have the following:

```
+------------+------+---------+  
|    Date    | Name | Number  |  
+------------+------+---------+  
| 2017-01-03 | Dude | 1000000 |  
| 2017-01-03 | Dude | 2000000 |  
| 2017-01-04 | Dude | 7000000 |  
| 2017-01-04 | Dude | 8750000 |  
+------------+------+---------+
```

I now want to take the averages for date 2017-01-03, but only if the difference between the max and min number for that day is above/below X. Of course my actual table is much larger, so removing the data and looping in VBA, for instance, is not helpful.

My ideal output would be:

```
+------------+------+---------+  
|    Date    | Name | AVGnum  |  
+------------+------+---------+  
| 2017-01-03 | Dude | X       |  
| 2017-01-04 | Dude | Y       |  
+------------+------+---------+
```

Where X and Y are the averages of the numbers if and only if the difference between the max and min on that day is above a specified X.

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: And what happens when the difference does not exceed X?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select date, name,
       (case when max(num) - min(num) > @X then avg(num) end) as avgnum
from t
group by date, name;
```

This puts `NULL`s in the places where the difference does not meet the condition.

If you want to filter out the rows, use `having` instead:

```
select date, name, avg(num) as avgnum
from t
group by date, name
having max(num) - min(num) > @X
```

Answer (score 0):

somthing like:

```
SELECT table.Date,
       table.Name,
       AVG(table.number)
  FROM table
 WHERE table.Date = '2017-01-03'
 GROUP BY table.Date,
       table.Name
HAVING MAX(table.Number) - MIN(table.Number) < X
   AND MAX(table.Number) - MIN(table.Number) > X
```

Be aware that only the numbers matching the having conditions would be taken in the AVG calculation.

With 'HAVING' you can use aggregate functions in GROUP BY.